# What is a non-heap type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management

I'm trying to use the `meliae` memory allocation analyser to track down some memory behaviour in an app.  But when I ask it to dump all the objects allocated, it does this:

```
Fatal Python error: type_traverse() called for non-heap type 'gi._gi.GObject'

Current thread 0x00007f4888fe2740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/meliae/scanner.py", line 71 in dump_all_referenced
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/meliae/scanner.py", line 141 in dump_all_objects
  File "<stdin>", line 2 in <module>
```

What is a non-heap type?  Given a Python object, is there a way to tell if it is of a non-heap type?